# Are hashcodes good for joins

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl, hashcode

I am new to Snowflake and want to know, can we use hashcodes for joining tables or finding unique records or deleting duplicate records in Snowflake(or in any other database in general)?
I am designing an ETL flow, what are the advantages or disadvantages of using hashcodes and why are they generally not used often in most Data warehousing designs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean hashing with something like md5_binary or sha1_binary then yes absolutely,

Binary values are half the byte length of the equivalent varchar length and so you should use that. The benefit of using hash-keys (effectively) is that you only need a single join column if for instance the natural keys of a table might be a composite key. Now you could instead a numeric/int data type, sequence key but that imposes a load order. Example only after the related dimension tables have loaded should you build the related fact table --- if you are doing that.

Data Vault prefers durable hash-keys because it does not impose any load ordering, load in any order independently.

Anyway I digress, yes hash-keys have great advantages, just make sure they're binary data types when loaded.

Comment: hashed keys used for joining can give false matches (see birthday paradox)

Comment: Thanks guys. But @MitchWheat what is the probability of that happening if my table contains let's say 200 million records.

Comment: read up on the birthday paradox....

Comment: less likely if you use sha1 though, yes there's plenty of content on the internet. I couldn't use something like murmur, not guaranteed to generate unique hash digests!